# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment" But it's a global variable

Tags: python, variables, global, local, discord.py

I am making a Python Discord bot with discord.py. I am relatively new to Python but have about eight years of experience with other languages. My problem is that I get the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prefix' referenced before assignment` even though I have defined `prefix` as a global variable. (I am using Python 3.6.8)

I have tried defining the variables outside the `on_ready` function, but I get the same result.

```
import discord;

client = discord.Client();

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Loading complete!')
  ...
  global prefix
  prefix = 'hello world'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  messageContents = message.content.lower()
  splitMessage = messageContents.split()
  try:
    splitMessage[0] = splitMessage[0].upper()lower()
  except:
    return
  if splitMessage[0]==prefix:
    ...
    (later in that if statement and a few nested ones)
    prefix = newPref

client.run('token')
```

I expected the output would be that it runs the code within the if statement, but instead I get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prefix' referenced before assignment` and no code is run.

The only thing I can think of being the problem is `prefix = newpref`. I tried:

```
global prefix
prefix = newpref
```

But then I got the error: `SyntaxError: name 'prefix' is used prior to global declaration` and the bot didn't start at all. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try the global statement *before you use prefix in the function* as suggested by the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope,
>   that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly
>   named variable in the outer scope.

**Short version:**

You need to declare your global variable outside the scope of your functions such as

```
#declaring the global variable
x = 10
def foobar():
    #accessing the outer scope variable by declaring it global
    global x
    #modifying the global variable
    x+=1
    print(x)
#calling the function
foobar()
```

**Long version:**

Basically, everything in python is an object and collections of those objects are called [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the
>   global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the
>   author of a module can use global variables in the module without
>   worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables.

So when you run your bot script, python treats it as a module that is running as the main script, with its own global scope.
When you declare a variable in a global scope, to use it in local scopes of certain functions you need to use the keyword `global` to access that global scope of your module.

Also, python does not *require* semi-colons to terminate statements (such as `client = discord.Client();`). Semicolons *can* be used to delimit statements if you wish to put multiple statements on the same line.